# How to make a tile base map?

Tags: java, awt

I was just wondering how I could make all of the 0's into squares and have the 1's left blank.

This is basically how I want it to look

```
int [][] map = {
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
```

This is where I draw all my Images

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
{
  super.paintComponent(g);

  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

  for (int row  = 0; row < map.length; row ++)
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < map[0].length; col++)
    {

    }
  }
```

Comment: There's no "blank" really on computer screen. So just draw a "wall" square when you have 0 and a "floor" square when you have 1. What's the problem?

Comment: This looks like you've simply pasted a homework template and are asking how to do it. What have ***you*** tried in order to solve it? Show us your attempt in a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Consider each index with its coordinates, what do they have in common?

```
{[0,0],[1,0],[2,0]},
{[0,1],[1,1],[2,1]},
{[0,2],[1,2],[2,2]}
```

Now that you have it, you may write your logic.